# Three join and groupby ln laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, group-by

Hello I am new with laravel and I need to do **two join** between three tables then **group  by** and **count** in another table then **join** the result of the group by with the **two join result**.I try to use two query the first one for the **two join** and the second query for the **group by** but i don't know how to join the two query.
This is my first query three tables: members, members_courses_assign and courses

```
$temp = DB::table('members')
  ->join('members_courses_assign', 'members.externalPersonKey', '=', 'members_courses_assign.externalPersonKey')
  ->join('courses', 'members_courses_assign.referenceNumber', '=', 'courses.referenceNumber')->where(['courses.termkey'=>$termK,'members_courses_assign.termkey'=>$termK])->get();
```

This is my second query

```
  $count= DB::table('files')
                   ->select('referenceNumber', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
                  ->where(['termkey'=>$termK])
                   ->groupBy('referenceNumber')
                   ->get();
```

Then i need to join the result of the first with the second, I try to join the 4 table first but the 4th table 'files' will ambiguity because the 'referenceNumber' is'not unique in the 'files' table.

Comment: what is the relationship between `files` and theother tables ?

Comment: there is no relationship between them just if I do a group by 'referenceNumber' to the 'files' table the 'referenceNumber' will be unique then I can join the 'files' table with the other tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, using `join()` with the 'count' subquery as the first argument, and passing a Closure as the second argument specifying the link between your main query and the subquery should work.

```
$temp = DB::table('members')
->join('members_courses_assign', 'members.externalPersonKey', '=', 'members_courses_assign.externalPersonKey')
->join('courses', 'members_courses_assign.referenceNumber', '=', 'courses.referenceNumber')
->join(DB::raw('(SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, referenceNumber FROM files WHERE termkey='.$termK.' GROUP BY referenceNumber) FileCount'), function($join)
{
    $join->on('courses.referenceNumber', '=', 'FileCount.referenceNumber');
})
->where(['courses.termkey'=>$termK,'members_courses_assign.termkey'=>$termK])
->get();
```